# How do I fix a Bootstrap tooltip showing at the end of the DOM instead of next to its selector

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

i have implemented twitter bootstraps Tooltip before.  But this time when I did it, the tooltip div shows at the end of the DOM immediately before the `</body>` tag.
I have the tooltip setup to work on any href rel="tooltip".  you can see the issue at http://papershare.ravennainteractive.com/publish/ middle of the page is (TEST) this link should be showing a tooltip.  when you hover the tooltip appears on the DOM (using Chrome inspector) but not visible on the page.

Its baffling to me why it would do this.  I have checked through the bootstrap site and googled for hours now trying to resolve on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here's your problem:

book.css line 44:

.tooltip { visibility: hidden; }